# Check if an application is on its first run with Kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

Basically, I want to have a screen/view that will open when the user opens up the app for the first time. This will be a login screen type of thing.

there are classes  SplashActivity

```
class SplashActivity : AppCompatActivity() {


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        //hiding title bar of this activity
        window.requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)
        //making this activity full screen
        window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash)

        //4second splash time
        Handler().postDelayed({
            //start main activity
            startActivity(Intent(this@SplashActivity, MyCustomAppIntro::class.java))
            //finish this activity
            finish()
        },2000)
    }
}
```

class MyCustomAppIntro

```
class MyCustomAppIntro : AppIntro() {




    companion object {
        fun startActivity(context: Context) {
            val intent = Intent(context, MyCustomAppIntro::class.java)
            context.startActivity(intent)

        }
    }
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setTransformer(AppIntroPageTransformerType.Depth)
        // You can customize your parallax parameters in the constructors.
        setTransformer(AppIntroPageTransformerType.Parallax(
                titleParallaxFactor = 1.0,
                imageParallaxFactor = -1.0,
                descriptionParallaxFactor = 2.0
        ))

             // Make sure you don't call setContentView!

        // Call addSlide passing your Fragments.
        // You can use AppIntroFragment to use a pre-built fragment
        addSlide(
            AppIntroFragment.newInstance(
            imageDrawable = R.drawable.ayana,
                backgroundDrawable = R.color.black,
                        description = "Привет мой друг"

        ))
        addSlide(
                AppIntroFragment.newInstance(
                        imageDrawable = R.drawable.ayana,
                        backgroundDrawable = R.color.black,
                        description = "Меня зовут AYANA"
        ))
        addSlide(
                AppIntroFragment.newInstance(
                        backgroundDrawable = R.drawable.screen_3

                ))
    }

    override fun onSkipPressed(currentFragment: Fragment?) {
        super.onSkipPressed(currentFragment)
        // Decide what to do when the user clicks on "Skip"
        val intent = Intent(this,MainActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent);


        finish()
    }

    override fun onDonePressed(currentFragment: Fragment?) {
        super.onDonePressed(currentFragment)
        val intent = Intent(this,MainActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent);
        finish()
    }
```

class MainActivity

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_activity_main)

        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON)



        about.setOnClickListener{
            val intent = Intent(this,ScondActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent);
        }


        val assistantFragment = AimyboxAssistantFragment()

        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().apply {
            replace(R.id.assistant_container, assistantFragment)
            commit()
        }
    }

    override fun onBackPressed() {
        val assistantFragment = (supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.assistant_container)
                as? AimyboxAssistantFragment)
        if (assistantFragment?.onBackPressed() != true) super.onBackPressed()
    }

}
```

We suggest to don't declare MyCustomAppIntro as your first Activity unless you want the intro to launch every time your app starts. Ideally you should show the AppIntro activity only once to the user, and you should hide it once completed (you can use a flag in the SharedPreferences) ????

Answer (score 1):

**Use SharedPreference for that Issue, its quite easy and simple approach:**

**Splash Activity:**

```
SharedPreference sharedpref = getApplicationContext.getSharedPreferences(SETTINGS_PREFERENCES,MODE_PRIVATE);

String token = sharedPreferences.getString("token", null);

if (token.equals("False") || token == null){

    //will call the view for the first and last time until cache is cleared

    //after trigger this login programmatically set the token value true thus you can solve the problem  
    
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpref.edit();
                                    editor.putString("token", "True");
                                    editor.apply();

}else{
    //do something or redirect to login or main activity
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much but need kotlin

Comment: Just go through the syntax editing, rest of the code is same.

Comment: it doesn't work , SharedPreferences errors

Comment: Hope you got syntax error, just go for kotlin syntax and rest of the logic is same

Comment: I'm sorry but I can do it

Comment: copy java codes to android studio and that  turns to kotlin automatically

Answer (score 1):

as @EmonHossainMunna suggested, `SharedPreferences` are the go, kotlin code will be as follows

```
        val sharedpref: SharedPreferences =
            getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(
                "com.example.android.your_application",
                MODE_PRIVATE
            )

        val token: String? = sharedpref.getString("token", null)
        if (token == "False" || token == null) {
            // rest of the FirstTime Logic here

            sharedpref.edit().putString("token", "true").apply()
        } else {
            // rest of the Not-FirstTime Logic here
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You also may want to check if `onCreate()` runs the first time:

```
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: ' if (savedInstanceState == null){
                startActivity(Intent(this@SplashActivity, MyCustomAppIntro::class.java))}
            else {
                startActivity(Intent(this@SplashActivity, MainActivity::class.java))}' does not work